# Counter for Rate Limit on Cloudflare for Different Endpoints in Request Traffic

Tags: security, cloudflare, rate-limiting, websecurity

I have 3 API endpoints which need same [**rate-limiting** on **Cloudflare**](https://developers.cloudflare.com/waf/rate-limiting-rules/request-rate/). So, I have clubbed them together.

The rule goes like this:

**If incoming requests match:**

```
Host = "https://www.x.com" AND URI Path = "/a"
OR
Host = "https://www.x.com" AND URI Path = "/b"
OR
Host = "https://www.x.com" AND URI Path = "/c"
```

(Notice the usage of AND and OR operators above)

**with the same characteristics:**

```
Header value of identifier
```

**When rate exceeds:**

```
10 requests in 1 minute
```

**Then take action:**

```
Block requests for 1 day
```

What happens out of the following:

- Are **individual counter buckets** created for paths `a`, `b` & `c`?

  So, only when a user makes 10 requests for path `a` (or 10 requests for path `b` or 10 requests for path `c`) within a minute, the user gets blocked for a day.
- Is a **common counter bucket** created for all paths `a`, `b` & `c` combined together?

  So, if a user makes 7 requests for path `a` and 3 requests for path `c` within a minute, the user gets blocked for a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are individual counter buckets created for paths a, b & c?
>
> So, only when a user makes 10 requests for path a (or 10 requests for path b or 10 requests for path c) within a minute, the user gets blocked for a day.

No, bucket only counts on `Header value of identifier` in this case.

You need to set `AND Path` condition additionally

[image]

> Is a common counter bucket created for all paths a, b & c combined together?
>
> So, if a user makes 7 requests for path a and 3 requests for path c within a minute, the user gets blocked for a day.

Yes. If you want to separate bucket for each path, you will have to do the thing above.

See this documentation in detail

https://developers.cloudflare.com/waf/rate-limiting-rules/request-rate/

> [image: a]